# Delete characters from a certain point

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, grep, tr

I want to get all the files that are written in bash so I use this command `IFBASH=$(grep -Fx #!/bin/bash *)`
It works.

Output: `test.sh:#!/bin/bash t      test2.sh:#!/bin/bash`

All this is saved in the variable $IFBASH.
Now I want to remove `:#!/bin/bash` 
so I used `LIST=$(echo "$IFBASH" | tr -d ':#!/bin/bash')`

Output:

```
   tet.h
   tet2.h
```

This is definitely not what I want.
Can someone give me a command that really works.

Comment: How about scripts written with the more correct `#! /bin/bash -` shebang, or `#! /bin/bash` or `#! /bin/bash -eu` or `#! /usr/bin/env bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That failed because `tr` takes a *list of characters* as input, not a string. So `echo abc | tr 'bca' 'def'` will print `fde` because it will change the `b` to an `f`, the `c` to a `d` and the `a` to an `e`.

You can do what you want either by telling `grep` to not include the parts you don't want (if your `grep` supports the `-l` option, as the one on Linux does) or use a tool that can replace strings, such as `sed`:

1. Use GNU `grep`

   ```
    ifbash=$(grep -lx '#!/bin/bash' *)
   ```
2. Use `sed` or `perl` or any other tool that can replace strings

   ```
    ifbash=$(grep -x '#!/bin/bash' * | sed 's|#!/bin/bash||')
   ```

   or

   ```
    ifbash=$(grep -x '#!/bin/bash' * | perl -pe 's|#!/bin/bash||')
   ```

Note that I removed the `-F` option as that isn't needed here and I changed `IFBASH` to `ifbash`. It is generally a good idea to avoid using capitalized variable names in shell scripts since by convention, the global environment variables are capitalized and that can lead to unexpected behavior if you use a name that is already defined system-wide.